# Entity Framework retrieving different instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I assumed that for a given ObjectContext, if I do a query and retrieve a unique object (i.e.using primary key(s)), a second query using the same ObjectContext would give me the very **same instance** of the object.

However, this is not necessarily the case.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Here is some code:
(in this case I have a composite key)

```
var x = context.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key1 == 1 && e.Key2 == 5);
var y = context.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key1 == 1 && e.Key2 == 5);  
var isSame = x == y;
```

**UPDATE**

I believe the answer to this problem lies in the MergeOption for the entities. I noticed that the ones that are not working are set to NoTracking, as opposed to the AppendOnly option which is the default. This is probably the root of the problem I am having.

Comment: What is the actual query for each.. you can kind of answer your own question based on what you have asked..

Comment: Entity Framework maintains a unique entry for every unique entity key in its cache (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx). So unless you change the entity key or remove the first object from the cache this should not happen. Do you have code to reproduce your observed behavior?

Comment: Yes I have code--I updated my question.

Comment: @Fernando can you check what EntityKey both x and y have? (Also I assume it should be e.Key **==** 5?)

Comment: I think my problem is the MergeOption setting.

Comment: @Fernando: Yes, MergeOption.NoTracking keeps all entities in a detached state and they are not kept in the cache of the context, thus the context can not return the same object again.

Comment: @Fernando: Do you want to post that as your answer? Or will you close the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to an incorrect MergeOption setting. In this particular case it was set incorrectly to NoTracking.